# Conditional rendering comments count React

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I am trying to show comments count of the post inside my React Component. I managed to show the amount, but some posts have zero comments. In this situation I want to render '0'. Right now my condition looks like this, but I don't understand what to put inside 'i want to show count here' part :(

```
{this.props.post.comments_count == null ? 'i want to show count here' : '0' }
```

Comment: You’d put the count there. Like if the count is in `props.post.comments_count` that’s what you’d put. Although the logic shown seems backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
{ this.props.post.comments_count || 0 }
```